# HTML / Javascript - Textarea glitch?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

With this code in my document,

```
<body>
<a style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Text area:</a><br>
<textarea id="html_code" style="
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
width: 650px;
height: 400px;
padding: 7.5px;
margin-top: 5px;
resize: vertical;" spellcheck="false"></textarea>

<script>

document.getElementById("html_code").value = '<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n</head>\n<body>\n<script>\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>';

</script>
</body>
```

there is an unexpected result. The text are not correctly displayed within the textarea.

Here is a [preview](http://prntscr.com/2upems) of the result of the above code.

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Define "The text are not correctly displayed within the textarea."

Comment: @Blaine Please look at the [preview](http://prntscr.com/2upems) link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are putting 
`<script>\n</script>`
 on

`'<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n</head>\n<body><script>\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>'`,

which is not treating as string in textarea but tag.

**UPDATE**

change from `</script>` to `<\/script>` does solve your problem.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RX97a/)

Comment: And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this

document.getElementById("html_code").innerHTML = '<!doctype    html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n</head>\n<body>\n<script>\n</script>\n</body>\n</html>';

make sure you [escape the html](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html) from the string, it's not showing here. Click edit on the answer to see it.

Comment: you have to escape the html. got me too for a second. It's not showing in the code black btw. Click edit on the answer to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Number one, **first one foremost** you do not want to add html markup code to a Textarea. If you need to add raw HTML to a container use a `div` or `p`. You can use the `ContentEditable` attribute option of the `div` for adding `html` markup to a container. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

You would add the markup to the contenteditable div like so: `document.getElementById("html_code").innerHTML =  '<!doctype html>\` If your adding this HTML to a div that is contenteditable that exist with-in a current DOM document you do not need the

```
'<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n</head>\n<body>\n<
```

portions of your code because you're adding a new document and a new body to a current document. That is not right. The only thing I see you need to add is the script and if that is the case you just need to add that script to the head of the document.

What are you wanting the end result to be?